# How can I create a h2 wrapped in a div in Draftail

Tags: wagtail, draftjs

I would like to allow my content editors to center-align content. To this aim, I want to add a DIV button to Draftail which wraps its children in a `div` with the `centered` class. The rendered result should be something like:

```
<div class"centered">Hello <h2>there</h2></div>
```

I'm able to create a new DIV block element in Draftail using `BlockFeature` and `BlockElementHandler`, but this block element cannot nest other block elements such as `H2`, so it's not generic enough.

Can someone post an example that shows how this is done?

ps I tried to adapt the 'stock' `EntityFeature` example, but this example is not that well documented (imho). I was unable to simplify it to do just the thing I need.

Comment: You'd be far better off using StreamField for this, rather than putting your headings inside a Draftail rich text field. With StreamField, the heading would be a separate content block for which you have full control over the HTML markup within your template, and you wouldn't be relying on one specific bit of HTML being embedded into your content.

Comment: @gasman I agree, I was staring at how to customize Draftail but StreamField is very suitable for this. Thanks!

Comment: @gasman will you move your comment into an answer? Comments aren't persistent on SO.